# Convert month and year as last day of the month in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two column - Month and Year in a table.

Need to concatenate these to get the last day of the month in date format.
For example, if Month =5 and Year =2020, the output needs to 31-May-20.

Similarly if Month =4 and Year=19, the output needs to be 30-APR-20.

Any idea how this can be done, is there any analytical functions in Oracle SQL that I can use to create this output.

DB version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0.

Comment: HINT : Check out the oracle function Last_day()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As years don't have the same number of digits,

- left pad them with `20` (as it seems you want *this century*),
- concatenate them with months (do the same - left pad them with `0` to get the full `YYYYMM` format, and
- use `LAST_DAY` function to get the final result

Something like this (I'm altering the session as my database speaks Croatian and format mask differs from yours) (sample data first; query you might need begins at line #5):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = english;

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mon-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (mon, yr) as
  2    (select '5', '2020' from dual union all
  3     select '4',   '19' from dual
  4    )
  5  select mon,
  6         yr,
  7         last_day(to_date(lpad(yr, 4, '20') || lpad(mon, 2, '0'), 'yyyymm')) result
  8  from test;

M YR   RESULT
- ---- -----------
5 2020 31-may-2020
4 19   30-apr-2019

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one:

```
LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(year||'-'||months||'-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach for other databases avoiding special functions

```
create or replace function f_ldom(adate in date) return date
is
begin
  return _ldom_mm_yyyy(to_number(to_char(adate,'MM')),to_number(to_char(adate,'YYYY')));
end;
/

create or replace function f_ldom_mm_yyyy(amon in number, ayear in number)      return date
is
  mon number;
  year number;
  lastday date;
begin
  if amon in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) then
    lastday := to_date('31'||to_char(amon,'00')||to_char(ayear,'0000'),'DDMMYYYY');
  else 
    if amon in (4,6,9,11) then
      lastday := to_date('30'||to_char(amon,'00')||to_char(ayear,'0000'),'DDMMYYYY');
    else
      if (amon = 2) then
        lastday := to_date('0103'||to_char(ayear,'0000'),'DDMMYYYY')-1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
  return lastday;
end;
/

select f_ldom(to_date('05-MAY-2010','DD-MON-YYYY'))"DATE" from dual;
select f_ldom(to_date('13-SEP-2018','DD-MON-YYYY'))"DATE" from dual;
select f_ldom(to_date('22-FEB-2000','DD-MON-YYYY'))"DATE" from dual;
select f_ldom(to_date('22-FEB-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'))"DATE" from dual;
select f_ldom(to_date('22-FEB-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'))"DATE" from dual;

select f_ldom_mm_yyyy(5,2010)"DATE" from dual;
select f_ldom_mm_yyyy(9,2018)"DATE" from dual;
select f_ldom_mm_yyyy(2,2000)"DATE" from dual;
select f_ldom_mm_yyyy(2,2019)"DATE" from dual;
select f_ldom_mm_yyyy(2,2020)"DATE" from dual;
```

this will give the following output:

```
Function created.
Function created.

DATE
31-MAY-10

DATE
30-SEP-18

DATE
29-FEB-00

DATE
28-FEB-19

DATE
29-FEB-20

DATE
31-MAY-10

DATE
30-SEP-18

DATE
29-FEB-00

DATE
28-FEB-19

DATE
29-FEB-20
```